# How to use data from from 1st row in the current row being read by the data reader?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, datareader

Suppose there's a situation where I need data from the 1st row (or any row already read) to be used in the row currently being read by the data reader. Is this possible with a data reader (without storing the data in a temp variable)? How?

Comment: Use DataTable for this purpose since DataReader only works in foreword only manner

Comment: No, you can't. That's how a stream behaves. Depending how much data you want to refer back, it's better to store them in variables or DataTable class. DataTable is not always approachable if data volume is really large.

Comment: "You can't recall what you forgot"